# Checking intersection of two sets by two values in each

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, intersection, set-theory

I need to find out if there is any intersection between two arrays with start and end value (wiki on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)). For example (just a few cases):

```
a = (10, float("inf"))
b = (8, float("inf"))
```

or

```
a = (10, 20)
b = (4, 25)
```

So, b contains a. How can I do this in python ? Are there any tools for this ?
Thanks

Comment: just `return a[0]>=b[0] and a[1]<=b[1]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That tests whether `a` is a subrange of `b`, which is a stronger statement than the two ranges simply overlapping at some interval.

Comment: true: in OP example `b` contains `a`

Comment: You already identified the logic for determining whether one interval contains another.  How were you not able to write `if` conditions for that?  Even then, the code was easy enough to find by searching for "Python interval contain".  How did those hits not solve your problem?  No attempt ...

Comment: What you show are not Python sets, though you can make such sets with the `sympy` library. Python sets must have finitely many values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just test bounds:

```
def contains(a,b):
    return a[0]>=b[0] and a[1]<=b[1]

a = (10, 20)
b = (4, 25)

print(contains(a,b))

a = (10, float("inf"))
b = (8, float("inf"))

print(contains(a,b))

b = (80, float("inf"))

print(contains(a,b))
```

prints:

```
True
True
False
```

(as last test makes the condition false)

As a side note, a python `set` is a collection of items, not a value range with start/stop as `tuple`, hence some possible confusion.

Also note that your example is confusing. If you want intersection, not inclusion, define an intersect method like this:

```
def intersects(a,b):
    return a[0] <= b[1] and b[0] <= a[1]
```

Comment: What if they aren't sorted? Wouldn't  `return min(a) >= min(b) and max(a) <= max(b)` be better?

Comment: Yes +1, it would actually be nice if Python 3 range objects implemented `>`, `>=` etc. comparisons (since they do already implement `==` and `!=`), so that one could do `range(4) > range(3)`, I guess a custom class implementation would be possible

Comment: @FHTMitchell yes, but in that case I suspect that it's overkill. the "sets" are likely to be ordered like min _then_ max.

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, but in the case of `float("inf")` it's not possible to create a `range`

Comment: Oh true, that would require an implementation of the operators for `linspace`or `np.arrange` objects, anyway it's definitely overkill for the OP I guess

Comment: and I'm noticing that I'm not answering the "intersect" aspect, just the "contains" aspect that OP provided as example.